# Is the Rocket Raid 2340 supported?

Tags: drivers

I have a server with a Rocket Raid 2340 card. I know it works in Solaris and FreeBSD, but strangely this old card doesn't work in Linux.
The internet is full of people asking for help, so I decided to add my voice to the party.

The company does not have any current drivers, and ubuntu has kernel 3.0,

So am I out of luck here ?

Comment: It doesn't work at all?  I thought that was another sata fakeraid card.

Comment: Nothing comes up. Nothing extra is loaded. I never thought I would see the day that something worked in FreeBSD, let alone Solaris, and not in Linux. It is not like this controller is brand new or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is indeed a fakeraid card, and the sata_mv driver supports its cousins, the 2300 and the 2310, but not the 2340.  Where I work we had a server with a rocket raid card that once decided to blow up the raid array for no good reason.  I now have Linux running on that hardware with the fake raid support disabled and using mdadm to manage the array, and the bios is still a little buggy ( it rounded down the size of the disks to the nearest gb, which screwed up grub ).  I would avoid these cards.